# How to add a hook to close event for a particular editor in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I need to do something when an editor for a particular document is closed. I have a following code:

```
FileObject fobj = FileUtil.toFileObject(file);
final DataObject dobj = DataObject.find(fobj);
if (dobj != null) {
    EditorCookie ec = dobj.getLookup().lookup(EditorCookie.class);
    StyledDocument doc = ec.openDocument();
    // Here I would like to add a listener for close event, for the editor window that was opened
}
```

Is there a way of doing this? Or can I at least hook a listener for global editor closing, so that I get notified of each editor window being closed? I guess in that case I would be somehow able to decide whether the given editor window is the one I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By accident I stumbled about something which may help you:

```
EditorCookie.Observable cookie = dataObject.getLookup().lookup(EditorCookie.Observable.class);
cookie.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    // Do your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep, seems exactly like what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found a working solution, however, it still feels like an ugly workaround. I do not understand why all solutions to my problems with NetBeans IDE look so ugly. I can see that the platform aims to prepare a nice space for creating new editors and other pluggable components, however, when one wants just to listen to existing components (Editors, etc.), it becomes a nightmare.

In my current solution I add a property change listener to TopComponent Registry and listen for a "tcClosed" property to change, and then I test whether it has an EditorCookie (so whether it is an editor) and whether the cookie is the same one that I want to listen to:

```
TopComponent.getRegistry().addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("tcClosed") && evt.getOldValue() == null) {
            EditorCookie cookie = ((TopComponent) evt.getNewValue()).getLookup().lookup(EditorCookie.class);
            // I have to remember editor cookie to compare it to the one that is closed
            // so that I can find out whether it is the editor I want to listen to
            if (cookie != null && cookie.equals(ParentClass.this.getRememberedEditorCookie())) {
                // Do my stuff
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However, if anyone knows a better solution, I will be happy to hear about it.